# C# LINQ Join Master - Detail , SelectMany

Tags: c#, linq

Below my example data:

```
List<Master> m = new List<Master>() { 
    new Master() { ID = 1, BoxName = "Red Box", 
        new Detail() { Code = 200, Description = "Pen", Process = true },
        new Detail() { Code = 201, Description = "Book", Process = true }
    },
    new Master() { ID = 2, BoxName = "Black Box",
        new Detail() { Code = 200, Description = "Pen", Process = false},
        new Detail() { Code = 202, Description = "Pencil", Process = false }
    },
    new Master() { ID = 3, BoxName = "Yellow Box", 
        new Detail()
    };
```

I want to query that data with expected result:

```
{ ID = 1, BoxName = "Red Box", Process = true (of the item true then process = true)},
{ ID = 2, BoxName = "Black Box", Process = false },
{ ID = 3, BoxName = "Yellow Box", Process = false (Without detail, proccess = false)}
```

When I use LINQ with SelectMany, Master data with ID 3 is disappears. This is my syntax

```
var data = m.SelectMany(x => x.Detail.Select(y => new { ID = x.ID, BoxName = "Red Box", 
       Process = (Master.Deatil.Count > 0 ? Convert.ToBoolean(y.Process) : false))
       .Distinct();
```

Then I got retruned data, but Box with ID == 3 is not included. Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: `SelectMany` is mostly used to flatten a list. Here you dont go over objects with lists so no need of that. A `Select` statement is more appropriate. `masterList.Select(m => new {ID = m.ID, BoxName = m.BoxName, Process = m.Detail.Any() && m.Detail.All(d => d.Process == true)});` should do the work

Comment: SelectMany is needed.  Try removing the Distinct and see if you get everything.   Distinct won't work unless you have a IEquality method in your class Master.

Comment: I can't understand your object initializer; afaiaa you can't just bang `new Detail(..)` into an init'r without a `SomePropertyName = ` leading it